# pyinstaller error, exe compilation error?

Tags: python

music player programming. ran into a problem. The program should play the file that I run using my program. For this, I formatted the code in exe. When I started using my exe an error occurred

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MP3.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "MP3.py", line 7, in music
pygame.error
[1980] Failed to execute script MP3
```

MP3.py -my python code/

```
import pygame 
import sys
f = str(sys.argv[1])
print(f) 
def music(f):
    pygame.init()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.mixer.music.load(f)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():


pygame.mixer.init(22050,-16,2)
music(f)
```

various methods do not help.
although the code with music playback works shortly and in exe as well as the output of the file that I launch by the program

this error

```
C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Projects\MP3\Test.mp3

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MP3.py", line 15, in <module>
    music(f)
  File "MP3.py", line 9, in music
    pygame.mixer.music.load(f)
pygame.error
[17280] Failed to execute script MP3
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first use `pygame.mixer.init` before using mixer to do anything you want. You can refer to [this document](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.init) for details about how to tweak the parameters of the mixer.

Comment: it didn’t help. The error is only when I format. The answer didn’t help me